# how can I dynamically attach sidebar components to multiple instances of sidebar?

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm new to React and building out a design a ran into a problem.

I have a component called SideBar. I am using this component two times, one on each side of the page.

The problem is that I would like to add different components to each instance of the SideBar component. These would be lists of various items and etc. I assumed I could next component tags but the sidebar component doesn't output.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SideBar from "./WorkspaceComponents/SideBar";
import ScrollerBox from "./WorkspaceComponents/SideBarComponents/ScrollerBox";

class Workspace extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main className="reely-workspace">
        <SideBar position="SideBarLeft">
          <ScrollerBox />
        </SideBar>
        <SideBar position="SideBarRight" />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Workspace;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `SideBar` Component a wrapper component which wraps around the content given in it.

**Making SideBar Component a Wrapper Component :**

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        // You can add any custom element here //
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

All your element passed inside the `SideBar` Component will now be rendered as a part of `SideBar` along with what it contains.

**Way to consume the wrapper component:**

```
<SideBar>
   <Content1></Content1>
   <Content2></Content2>
   <Content3></Content3>
</SideBar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sidebar component should receive a `children` prop and render it out.

Something like this:

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    const {children} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <h1>Sidebar</h1>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Check out this post on react docs to understand how to compose react components: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html